# Java spring-mongo-data Mongodb query for group and projection logic

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have below 3 sample records:

```
    {
      "_id" : "0cc5c468-2105-11ee-ad68-15d467e62by4d",
      "storeId" : "3070",
      "paymentType" : "cash",
      "total" : {"$numberDecimal": "100"}
    },
{
      "_id" : "1111111-2105-11ee-ad68-15d467e62by4d",
      "storeId" : "3070",
      "paymentType" : "cash",
      "total" : {"$numberDecimal": "100"}
    },
    {
      "_id" : "0cc5c468-2105-11ee-ad68-15d467e62by4d",
      "storeId" : "3070",
      "paymentType" : "creditCard",
      "total" : {"$numberDecimal": "50"}
    }
```

I am trying to write some grouping and projection logic in which the desired output from above sample data should be as below:

```
StoreId | Cash Payment | Card Payment | Total Amount Cash + Card
3070        200               50                250
```

The last column can ofcourse be ignored but i need this kind of output from mongodb in java.
I have tried many things and below is the code I have so far which is not giving desired output, it gives me two separate records for card payment and cash payment types.

```
GroupOperation groupingLogic() {
        return group("storeId", "paymentType")
                .first("storeId").as("storeId")
                .first("paymentType").as("paymentType")
                .sum(TOTAL).as(TOTAL);
    }
```

I am not sure how to get output as expected above with java mongodb code .

Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group and add up some data from your MongoDB collection. Here's how you can do it using Java with Spring Data MongoDB:

**If You want to group the data by the "storeId" and sum the amounts for different payment types ("cash" and "creditCard"). Here's how you can do that:**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;

// ...

GroupOperation groupingLogic() {
    return Aggregation.group("storeId")
        .sum(
            ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("paymentType").is("cash")).then("$total.$numberDecimal").otherwise(0)
        ).as("cashPayment")
        .sum(
            ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("paymentType").is("creditCard")).then("$total.$numberDecimal").otherwise(0)
        ).as("cardPayment")
        .sum("$total.$numberDecimal").as("totalAmountCashCard");
}
```

**To show in your format. Here's how you can do that:**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation;


ProjectionOperation projectionLogic() {
    return Aggregation.project()
        .and("storeId").as("StoreId")
        .and("cashPayment").as("Cash Payment")
        .and("cardPayment").as("Card Payment")
        .and("totalAmountCashCard").as("Total Amount Cash + Card");
}
```

**Putting It All Together:**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class YourService {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public YourService(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    public List<YourOutputType> getGroupedData() {
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            groupingLogic(),
            projectionLogic()
        );

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "yourCollectionName", YourOutputType.class).getMappedResults();
    }
}
```

**Remember to replace yourCollectionName with the actual name** of your MongoDB collection and YourOutputType with the appropriate class that matches the expected output.

Comment: but hardcoding `.is("cash")` and `.is("creditCard")` is not desirable. tomorrow there could possibly be more types of payment options then we will again need to add more conditions right?

Comment: getting error "field name cannot start with $"

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

1. We need to group by 2 parameters (`storeId` + `paymentType`) and sum `paymentType's` total amount.
2. We sum `total amount` for all `paymentType`s for each `storeId`.
3. We need to use `$arrayToObject` to pivot each `paymentType` into field.
4. With other operators we assamble expected result.

---

```
{
   "Total Amount": NumberDecimal("250"),
   "cash": NumberDecimal("200"),
   "creditCard": NumberDecimal("50"),
   "storeId": "3070"
}
```

**Note:** `cash`, `creditCard`, `check`, etc. are dynamically filled. If any `storeId` has no such payment types, these fields may not be there.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        storeId: "$storeId",
        paymentType: "$paymentType"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.storeId",
      paymentType: {
        $push: {
          "k": "$_id.paymentType",
          "v": "$total"
        }
      },
      "total": {
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$paymentType",
          [
            {
              "k": "storeId",
              "v": "$_id"
            },
            {
              "k": "Total Amount",
              "v": "$total"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l07lEzwQfTb)

#### Java - complex aggregation pipeline

```
private static AggregationOperation replaceWith() {
    return ctx -> Document.parse("{" +
        "'$replaceWith': {" +
            "'$arrayToObject': {" +
                "..." +
            "}" +
        "}"+
    "}")
}
```

Comment: thanks, the mongo query works as expected but I didnt understand what to do with this replaceWith() java function. Should I just paste the entire replace block from mongo query inside this? Or is there any better way to use if we are using spring-data-mongo ?

Comment: @jarvo69 Yes. Instead of translating each agregation pipeline to Spring data syntax (which is horrible for the complex queries), just parse them as JSON with `Document.parse()` method.

Comment: What about this one?

`{
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.storeId",
      paymentType: {
        $push: {
          "k": "$_id.paymentType",
          "v": "$total"
        }
      },
      "total": {
        $sum: "$total"
      }
    }
  },`

how do i add this one in java? Can you please provide java equivalent for the same?

Comment: @jarvo69 Sure. `private static AggregationOperation group1() {return ctx -> Document.parse(put here 1st pipeline)}`, `private static AggregationOperation group2() {return ctx -> Document.parse(put here 2nd pipeline)}`, etc.